# YouTube iframe API playVideo() stopped working

Tags: youtube, youtube-iframe-api

Is anybody else having issues with the YouTube APIs at the moment? About 2.5hrs ago I had reports from two different clients that their playback on sites had stopped working. They all appear to be functioning correctly on the website side of things but the returned `YT.player` object has no `playVideo()` method and never fires `onReady`. No code has changed on either of these things for months.

A URL you can view the problem on is here (though the scripts are minified) - http://brisbanepowerhouse.org/videos/the-removalists-david-williamson-interview/
You could also try the first video on this page (unminified) - http://thenewdaily.com.au/videos/?author_name=susannah-guthrie - but it is pretty regularly updated with content and there is no guarantee that it will still be a YouTube video at #1 by the time someone looks (the site also uses Vimeo embeds)

cheers!

Comment: I should point out that in both cases the YouTube video should begin playback after the first time the overlay is clicked.

Comment: Hi Popsi, you ever got this solved? having the same problem

Comment: Sorry Redox, not really. It just fixed itself a few hours later, I guess something was going on on there end. Hopefully yours sorts itself out soon too! Wish I could help more..